# animate image to bring it out of dialog box

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make an image (which is inside a dialog box in an activity) to fly from inside the dialog box to right-bottom corner of main activity(bring image out of dialog box).But i am only able to make it fly to the right-bottom corner of dialog box. Image is not coming out of dialog box. Here is my xml code. Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android android:shareInterpolator="false">
<scale 
    android:fromXScale="8.0" android:fromYScale="8.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:duration="1000" />
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:startOffset="500" 
    android:duration="500" />
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"/>
<translate android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="50%"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="50%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

Comment: now its complete. please have a look